# Change \abovecaptionskip for some floats only

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I'd like to change the `\abovecaptionskip` (space between figure and caption) for the listing floats of the `minted` package only.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use package `caption` and its `\captionsetup`. For `listing` it must be inside a group to hold it local or alternetively use the new environment `mylisting`. For a default `figure` environment it can be inside and is then local by default

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}
\newenvironment{mylisting}[1][H]
  {\captionsetup{aboveskip=-0.2\normalbaselineskip}\begin{listing}[#1]}
  {\end{listing}}
\begin{document}

\bgroup
\captionsetup{aboveskip=-0.2\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}{c}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
  { do nothing }
end;
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a listing.}\label{lst:example}
\end{listing}
\egroup

\begin{mylisting}[H]
\begin{minted}{c}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
  { do nothing }
end;
\end{minted}
\caption{Example of a listing.}\label{lst:example}
\end{mylisting}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup{aboveskip=60pt}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set/restore the aboveskip settings automatically for the figure and listing floats?

Comment: Would `\captionsetup[listing]{aboveskip=0pt}` work also?

Comment: @Mike M: see edited answer for a new environment `mylisting` which sets the skip itself locally

Comment: @lockstep: how about trying it?? I suppose that your computer won't explode if it doesn't work ... :-))

Comment: @lockstep: It would work if either the `minted` package is adapted to the `caption` package, or if the `caption` package is adapted to the `minted` package. Unfortunately both is not the case :-(  (Have put this on my TODO list.)

Comment: I don't have minted installed, or at least I think so -- otherwise I *would* have tried. :-)

Comment: Well, I tried, but I don't invoke `--shell-escape` right now. Perhaps another time. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: maybe that you haven't installed -shell-escape ... :-)